# Error with sorting code in C

Tags: c

I think there was something wrong with the algorithm.
It shows wrong answers.
I changed every line by line, but I didn't get the proper answer.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void sort(int a[],int n)
{
    int gap,i,j,temp;
    for(gap=n;gap>0;gap/=2)
    {
        for(i=gap;i<n;i+=1)
        {
            temp=a[i];

            for(j=i;j>=gap&&a[j]>temp;j=gap)
                a[j]=a[j];

            a[j]=temp;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[20],i,n;

    printf("Number of elements:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter array elements:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);

    printf("Array elements before the sort:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        printf("%d",a[i]);

    sort(a,n);

    printf("\nAfter sort:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Please help me with this code.

Comment: Please show sample input and output and compare to desired output. What is wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're right emely,There were some issues in your algorithm.
In the 6th line the gap should be n/2, not n.
And in the 12th line it should be j-gap.

After correcting those errors,I rewrote the code.
**Hope it might help.
Cheers.**

```
#include<stdio.h>

void sort(int a[],int n)
{
    int gap,i,j,temp;
    for(gap=n/2;gap>0;gap/=2)
    {
        for(i=gap;i<n;i+=1)
        {
            temp=a[i];

            for(j=i;j>=gap&&a[j-gap]>temp;j-=gap)
                a[j]=a[j-gap];

            a[j]=temp;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[20],i,n;

    printf("Number of elements:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter array elements:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);

    printf("Array elements before the sort:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        printf("%d",a[i]);

    sort(a,n);

    printf("\nAfter shell sort:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thnx Sachin, Actually you're your code is working properly. And thnx with the guidance !